# Continuously Display Buffered Image in JFrame after Button Click

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, opencv

I am writing a program to continuously process and display the video stream from an `OpenCV` `VideoCapture` object in Java. I have set up a `JFrame` with controls to select the appropriate video source and then click a button to begin processing images from the source and displaying the result in an 'ImagePanel' (see code below) over a continuous loop.

The first problem that I encountered was that the `ActionListener` for the button press was "freezing" the `JFrame`. I found that if I hard-coded the video source directly into the code and bypassed the button press the `VideoCapture` images displayed on the `ImagePanel` as expected. I discovered the solution to the "button freezing" problem was to execute the function call made in the button's action listener in a separate thread.

Now the `JFrame` no longer freezes but **the `ImagePanel` no longer displays the images I am reading from the `VideoCapture` object. Why?**

I'm assuming this might be because the code is executing on a separate thread so the UI can't update properly but I'm not very familiar with threads in this context. This is my first stackoverflow question. Normally I am able to find an answer already posted on my topic of interest but no luck on this one. Please advise.

The following is quick simplification of my problem. I've cut down as much as I felt comfortable with to provide the basic class files to reproduce my problem.

**ImagePanel.java** - custom JPanel for displaying buffered images

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7065581626827263107L;
    private BufferedImage image; 

    public BufferedImage getImage(){  
        return image;  
    }  
    public void setImage(BufferedImage newImage){  
        image=newImage;  
    } 

    public BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat matrix){
        int cols = matrix.cols();  
        int rows = matrix.rows();  
        int elemSize = (int)matrix.elemSize();  
        byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];  
        int type;  
        matrix.get(0, 0, data);  

        switch (matrix.channels()) {  
        case 1:  
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;  
            break;  
        case 3:  
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;  
            //BGR to RGB 
            byte b;  

            //Swap blue and red bytes
            for(int i=0; i<data.length; i=i+3) {  
                b = data[i];  
                  data[i] = data[i+2];  
                  data[i+2] = b;  
            }  
            break;  
        default:  
            return null;  
        }  

        //Create the new buffered image from the byte array data
        BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, type);  
        image2.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, cols, rows, data);  
        return image2;  
    }

    @Override  
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){  
       super.paintComponent(g);   
       BufferedImage temp = this.getImage();  

       //Draw the buffered image
       if(temp != null)
           g.drawImage(temp,0,0,640,480, this);  //temp.getWidth() temp.getHeight()
    }  
}
```

**TestPanel.java** - Holds UI controls and ImagePanel for displaying images

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {  
    //Selects the video input device for OpenCV
    private static final int VIDEO_INPUT_DEVICE = 1;

    public static final int PANE_HEIGHT = 700;
    public static final int PANE_WIDTH = 710;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    private JTextField ipField, usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JLabel feedbackLabel;

    private JPanel controlsPanel, finishedPanel;
    private ImagePanel imagePanel;
    private JButton captureButton, finishedButton;

    // Constructor  
    public TestPanel(){  
        super();  
        this.setSize(710, 600);
        controlsPanel = new JPanel();
        controlsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        finishedPanel = new JPanel();
        finishedPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        imagePanel.setSize(640, 480);

        captureButton = new JButton("Fetch Video Feed");
        setCaptureButtonListener();
        finishedButton = new JButton("Finished Calibration");

        ipField = new JTextField("Enter Camera IP");
        usernameField = new JTextField("Enter Username");
        passwordField = new JPasswordField("Enter Password");
        feedbackLabel = new JLabel();

        // Add Controls
        controlsPanel.add(captureButton);
        controlsPanel.add(ipField);
        controlsPanel.add(usernameField);
        controlsPanel.add(passwordField);
        controlsPanel.add(feedbackLabel);
        finishedPanel.add(finishedButton);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 10, 10, 10));
        this.add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15), BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(finishedPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }  

    public void setImageWithMat(Mat newimage){  
      imagePanel.setImage(this.matToBufferedImage(newimage));  
      return;  
    }  

    /**  
     * Converts/writes a Mat into a BufferedImage.  
     *  
     * @param matrix Mat of type CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC1  
     * @return BufferedImage of type TYPE_3BYTE_BGR or TYPE_BYTE_GRAY  
     */  
    public BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat matrix) {  
        return imagePanel.matToBufferedImage(matrix);
    } 

    /**
     * Set action listener for capture button.
     */
    private void setCaptureButtonListener(){
        captureButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runSingleCalibration();
                }
                });

            }

          });
    }

    /**
     * Runs calibration for one video input stream.
     */
    private void runSingleCalibration(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        // Load the native library.  
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        //Get video input
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(VIDEO_INPUT_DEVICE);
        Mat image = new Mat();
        while(capture.read(image)){
            // Apply the GaussianBlur
            Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(19,19),0,0);
            //Output the images to their respective frames
            this.setImageWithMat(image);  
            this.repaint();
        }
        //Release the capture device
        capture.release();
    }
}
```

**TestCV.java** - simple JFrame to hold the TestPanel

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestCV {
private static JFrame frame;

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Jframe.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    if(frame == null){
        frame = new JFrame("RC Tracking");
    }

    frame.setContentPane(new TestPanel());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(710, 710);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing frame application's GUI.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I got to say, the OpenCV examples are not particularly good at following the single threaded rules of Swing...

Comment: `setImage(..)`  Where is that method called?  Please answer in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: add `repaint` in `setImage`...before the redundant `return`, you may need to make the `image` `volatile`